# Auth does not work on app engine

Tags: google-app-engine

I'm trying to use the given authentication methods for app engine:

```
handlers:
- url: /static
  static_dir: src/static

- url: /admin/.*
  script: src.app
  login: admin

- url: /client/.*
  script: src.app
  login: required

- url: /.*
  script: src.app
  login: optional
```

But the authentication does not work when I navigate to `/client` or `/admin`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect the reason is that the `/client/.*` and `/admin/.*` URL patterns don't cover the `/client` and `/admin` paths which are actually caught by the `/.*` pattern.

To confirm you could:

- make requests for `/admin/foo` or `/client/blah`, the auth should kick in for these
- temporarily change the **login** option for `/.*` from **optional** to **required**, the auth should kick in for `/client` and `/admin` as well

If confirmed the fix would be to just add explicit rules for `/client` and `/admin` (keep the `/client/.*` and `/admin/.*` ones as well, of course).